# Is there a way to fill polygons on HERE maps with custom textures or patterns for iOS apps?

Tags: ios, swift, here-api, heremaps, heremaps-ios-sdk

I am building an iOS app using HERE maps SDK.

I need to fill the area of my polygon with images/textures/patterns. The `NMAMapPolygon.customPattern` adds the image as a pattern along the borders of the polygon.

Is there a way where I can fill the entire region of the polygon with the image (in a repetitive manner like a texture)?

Comment: Still waiting for an answer. Any help/leads will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Would it be an option for you to use NMAMapLocalModel instead of NMAMapPolygon?